# backup program that comes with 16.04

Tags: backup, deja-dup

how do I use backup program that comes installed in 16.04 ?  how do I know what is being backed up before I try to use backup files?

Comment: See the "folders to save"?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Backups application, from the pane on the left side click *Folders to save*, and click the **+** button to add another folder to the list of backed up folders. There are other options on the pane on the left side for Folders to ignore, Storage location and Scheduling. If you make a mistake, select a folder to un-save and click the **-** button to remove that folder from the list of backed up folders.

[image]